# Simplified wait on Serverless AWS step function

Tags: python-3.x, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

I've written AWS Step function via Serverless. The logic looks like below

```
1. Execute Job
2. Get job status 
3. Check if job succeeded 
4. If not succeded wait for 60 seconds
```

For now, I've written step function defined as below

```
...
stepFunctions: 
  stateMachines: 
    myStateMachine: 
       definition:
         states: 
           ...
           Execute Job: 
             ... 
           Get Job Status: 
             Type: Task 
             Next: Is Job Succeeded?
             # This job check if job is succeeded or not and sets a variable 
             # job_succeeded = true
           Is Job Succeeded?
             Type: Choice
             Choices:
             - Variable: "$.job_succeded"
               BooleanEquals: true
               Next: Next Lambda Function  
             Default: Wait for job
           Wait for job:
             Type: Wait
             Seconds: 60
             Next: Get Job Status
           Next Lambda Function: 
              ...
           ...
```

**This perfectly works!**

But the problem, I've to write 4 lambdas for each different each job executed asynchronously, so if there 4 such tasks to be done there will be 4 * 4 steps i.e. 16 steps.

This makes it look like there are lots of lambdas in step function and it is hard to see the actual flow.

These 4 functions could be summarised as pseduo-code below

```
job_succeded = false
while job is not complete:
    job_succeded = get_job_status() 
    if not job_succeded:
        sleep 60 seconds
```

Potential solution could be

```
stepFunctions: 
  stateMachines: 
    myStateMachine: 
       definition:
         states: 
           ...
           Execute Job: 
             ... 
           Get Job Status: 
             Type: RepeatWhile
             Condition:
             - Variable: "$.job_succeded"
               BooleanEquals: true
               Next: Next Lambda Function
             WaitPeriod: 60 seconds 
             # This job check if job is succeeded or not and sets a variable 
             # job_succeeded = true
           Next Lambda Function: 
              ...
           ...
```

I understand that this is not the current case but this could simplify lots of workflows.
Is there any other way to simplify this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to step functions! They are unfortunately very bloated when written down. I dont know if this helps, but for something simple like this, I will use one lambda function for all my tasks.

You can define your step functions with additional parameters to tell your function what to execute

```
  Task_1:
    Type: Task
    Resource:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - MyLambdaFunction
        - Arn
    Parameters:
      execute: task_1
    Next: Task_2

  Task_2:
    Type: Task
    Resource:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - MyLambdaFunction
        - Arn
    Parameters:
      execute: task_2
    Next: Task_3
```

In your lambda function, just setup some simple if statements:

```
  if (event.execute === 'task_1') {
    // run task 1 code
  }
  else if (event.execute === 'task_2') {
    // run task 2 code
  }
```

I cant quite tell what youre trying to do in your question, but you can also output variables from your lambda, which then trigger different steps. You can use choice states for this e.g.

```
      ChoiceState:
        Type: Choice
        Choices:
          # response from lambda should be {executing: 'task_1', status: 'running'}
          - Variable: "$.executing" 
            StringEquals: task_1
          - Variable: "$.status"
            StringEquals: running
          Next: Wait

        - And:
          - Variable: "$.executing"
            StringEquals: task_1
          - Variable: "$.status"
            StringEquals: done
          Next: Task_2

        - And:
          - Variable: "$.executing"
            StringEquals: task_2
          - Variable: "$.status"
            StringEquals: running
          Next: Wait

        - And:
          - Variable: "$.executing"
            StringEquals: task_2
          - Variable: "$.status"
            StringEquals: done
          Next: Completed

        Wait:
          Type: Wait
          Seconds: 10
          Next: CheckExecution

        Completed:
          Type: Succeed

      CheckExecution:
        Type: Task
        Resource:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - MyLambdaFunction
            - Arn
        Next: ChoiceState
```

This isn't a full solution as it would be too complicated to write down here. But hopefully gives you some additional ideas to play with

Also, depending on how your state machine runs, this method provides a performance boost as you minimise lambda cold starts.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I think what you're trying to say is that handle the control flow within the lambda. But IMHO, the step function is meant to be for handling the workflow, step function should control the workflow and not the code.

Comment: The lambda doesn’t control the workflow. It can’t do anything unless step functions ask it to. Lambda just does what’s it’s told. It’s dumb to the workflow sequence.

Comment: Lambda takes input from step function, does something, sends response to step function. Based on response, step function chooses next step.